# Replace or substring first set of numbers with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am struggling to find a way to get only the first set of numbers in a file name in PowerShell. The file names can be similar to the ones below but I only want to get the first string of numbers and nothing else.

Example file names:

```
123456 (12).csv
123456abc.csv
123456(Copy 1).csv
123456 (Copy 1).csv
```

What I am currently attempting:

```
$test = "123456 (12).csv" 
$POPieces = $test -match "^[0-9\s]+$" 
Write-Host $POPieces
```

What I'd expect from above:

```
123456
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code for us to demonstrate an alternative/better fit solution or debug yours for you.

Comment: I have been overwriting most of what I tried with the next try so I don't remember most of it.  I have tried about 20 different options and even found some that work perfect in the Regex test sites but in PowerShell do not. I have tried both .split and replace. This is the last try I did. $test = "123456 (12).csv"
$POPieces = $test -match "^[0-9\s]+$"
write-host $POPieces. so far I have been able to return all numbers but that includes numbers in parenthesis.

Comment: `$test -match '^\d+'; $matches[0]`

Comment: `$` anchors it to the end, `^` anchors to the beginning, so you're telling powershell to match a regex that has one or more numbers or spaces, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The `-match` operator stores the matches in the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$matches`. However, your regular expression includes not only digits, but also whitespace (`\s`), so you won't necessarily get just the number. Change the expression to `^\d+` to match only a number at the beginning of the string. Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0) to enumerate the files, as [Martin Brandl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647455/1630171) suggested.

```
$POPieces = Get-ChildItem 'C:\root\folder' -Filter '*.csv' |
            Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d+' } |
            ForEach-Object { $matches[0] }
```